# How to make python script run or all files in a directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ncdf4

I have a script that converts a part of an nc file to a csv file. The script itself works, but the problem is that I would need to specify the exact directory including the name of the file and output csv. I am interested in running the script for all nc files from folder test1 and converting it to csv's in folder test2 with the same name. I attempted modifying the script but it hasn't worked. Here is my script.

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import num2date, date2num, date2index
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
import sys
import os

path = r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\test1"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    netcdf_file = r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\test1\\"+filename
    csv_file = r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\test2\\"+filename

    f = netCDF4.Dataset(netcdf_file)
    ssha = f.variables["ssha"]
    lon = f.variables['lon']
    lat = f.variables['lat']
    #time = f.variables['time']
    timedim = ssha.dimensions[0]
    times = f.variables[timedim]
    dates = num2date(times[:], times.units)

    dates = [date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for date in dates]
    lon_list= list(lon)
    lat_list = list(lat)
    ssha_list = list(ssha)
    lon_list = [x-360 if x>= 180 else x for x in lon_list]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':dates,'Longitude':lon_list,'Latitude':lat_list,'SSHA':ssha_list})
    df.to_csv(csv_file)
```

My failed attempt at modifying the script was

```
path = r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\test1"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    netcdf_file = r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\test1\\"+filename
    csv_file = r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\test2\\"+filename
```

Previously, it would have been

```
netcdf_file = r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\test1\\example1.nc"
csv_file = r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\test2\\exampleresult.csv"
```

where example1 was the nc file name and exampleresult would be the csv name.

Comment: Is your coded correctly indented? Because dont seems to be in the code that you posted above.

Comment: Post the error, please.

Comment: Sorry, I indented it. The error is that it would only create a csv for the first file in the directory and not the others.

Comment: df.to_csv(csv_file) has to be indented too, is it?

Comment: I figured it out! All I had to do was add +".csv" to the end of the csv_file line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob module to get a list of files with .nc extensions.

```
import glob

for netcdf_file in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\chz08006\Documents\test1\*.nc'):
    print(netcdf_file)
```

You can use os.path.split to split the file path into a parent directory path and file name.

```
import glob
import os

for netcdf_file in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\chz08006\Documents\test1\*.nc'):
    directory, ncfilename = os.path.split(netcdf_file)
    print(directory)        # C:\Users\chz08006\Documents\test1
    print(ncfilename)       # *.nc
```

You can use os.path.splitext to split the file name and extension.

```
for netcdf_file in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\chz08006\Documents\test1\*.nc'):
    directory, ncfilename = os.path.split(netcdf_file)
    print(directory)        # C:\Users\chz08006\Documents\test1
    print(ncfilename)       # filename.nc

    name, ext = os.path.splitext(ncfilename)
    print(name)             # filename
    print(ext)              # nc
```

Now you can build CSV file name, then you can use os.path.join to build CSV file path.

```
import glob
import os

csvparent = r"C:\Users\chz08006\Documents\test2"

for netcdf_file in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\link\test1\*.nc'):
    directory, ncfilename = os.path.split(netcdf_file)
    print(directory)        # C:\Users\chz08006\Documents\test1
    print(ncfilename)       # *.nc

    name, ext = os.path.splitext(ncfilename)
    print(name)             # filename
    print(ext)              # nc

    csvname = name + ".csv"
    csvpath = os.path.join(csvparent, csvname)
    print(csvpath)          # C:\Users\chz08006\Documents\test2\filename.csv
```

Now, variable csvpath contains what you need. It is the path to the CSV file with the same name as *.nc file but .csv extension and is inside the test2 directory.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Would suggest to use `pathlib.Path` instead, it's even nicer for splitting files from their directories and extensions. If you have `p = Path('qwerty/asdf.txt')` then `p.parent` is the directory the file is in and `p.stem` is the filename without the extension.